# group_by error "target of assignment expands to non-language object" in R

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, group-by

I have a couple of datasets and i want to make new dataframes for each dataset with some statistics.

The names of my datasets are:

```
01P004
01P005
01P006
etc.
```

And this is how the data looks like:

```
  description    result_timestamp water_level_validation_measurement
1      98P001 2013-01-02 12:00:00                               2.49
2      98P001 2013-02-26 12:00:00                               1.10
3      98P001 2013-03-14 12:00:00                               1.09
4      98P001 2013-03-28 12:00:00                               1.08
5      98P001 2013-04-10 12:00:00                               1.04
6      98P001 2013-04-22 12:00:00                               0.99
```

So i created a for loop to go over the datasets

```
Files <- mget(ls(pattern='*[0-9][0-9][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9]*'))

for (i in 1:length(Files)){
  paste0("Stat", names(Files[i])) <- Files[[i]] %>%
    group_by(Files[[i]]$description)) %>%
    summarise(GG = mean(Files[[i]]$water_level_validation_measurement), 
              RHG = quantile(Files[[i]]$water_level_validation_measurement, .9),
               RLG = quantile(Files[[i]]$water_level_validation_measurement, .1))
}
```

But i have some troubles with finding a working code. This one gives the following error

```
 Error in paste0("Stat", names(Files[i])) <- Files[[i]] %>% group_by(Files[[i]]$description) %>%  : 
   target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Does somebody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need `assign` if you want objects to be created.  I recommend you to keep it in the `list` itself

Comment: Where do i need to add the assign function?